# Prove set of 5 elements of $M_{2\times 2}$ is linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove if a set of $5$ elements of $M_{2\times 2}$ is linearly independent.

Since I have $5$ elements I think it's impossible for it to be independent since when I sum up these matrices I'll have $4$ equations describing $5$ variables $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5$ which will make my system undetermined and thus won't have one unique solution. Is this correct?
The set is the following

$$
S=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}.
$$
Suppose this set is lineary dependent, then for some nontrivial $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5$
$$
c_1\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\-1 & 1\end{pmatrix}+c_2\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}+c_3\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}+c_4\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}+c_5\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 1\end{pmatrix}=0
$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}c_1+c_3-c_4+c_5 & c_1+c_2+2c_3+c_5\\-c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5 & c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5\end{pmatrix}=0$$

Which gives

$$
\begin{cases}
c_1+c_3-c_4+c_5=0 \\
c_1+c_2+2c_3+c_5=0 \\
-c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5=0 \\
c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4+c_5=0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
 And if that's the case how can I formally express this or is it neccesary to write all the problem until I get to the point where I get $4$ equations of $5$ variables.

Comment: You can use $c1\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+c2\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}+c3\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}+c4\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, no?

Comment: As I see, you say matrix in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, right? Second, just hint, you can see that the dimension of a vector space of matrices, will be less or equal to the number of elements in the matrix.

Comment: I have edited the question giving the elements of the set, sorry for not prompting this up.

Comment: @Yudop So with Ross Millikan's help you have found that $c_1=c_5=0,c_2=2,c_3=c_4=-1$ gives a linear dependence relation. So please either (1) accept his answer, or (2) (if you think he did not help and you did it on your own) put up your own answer and then accept it 48 hours later. That way the system can mark this question as answered and others can stop wasting time looking at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your four equations.  Now just try to solve them by your favorite method.  The last two (subtract them) tell you $c1=0$.  Then the second and last give you $c3=c4$.  Keep going.  You will find at least one variable unconstrained.

Comment: Since $c4=c3$ in ecuation 1 $c5=0$ and in ecuation 3 $c2=-2c3$, so in ecuation 4 $c3=0$, hence $c1=c2=c3=c4=c4=c5=0$ So does this prove it's linearly independent?

Comment: No, all your equations come down to $c2=-2c3=-2c4, c1=c5=0$ but you can pick $c2$ as whatever you like.  You lost converting the $c4$ to $c3$ in equation 4.

Comment: Thanks I can see my error, so since $c2=-2c3=-2c4$ it can't be an independent set.